# Reference a variable that cannot be resolved at compile-time. (java)

Tags: java, class, dynamic, compiler-errors

I'm creating a program where I create class references during runtime using e.g:

```
String hero1builder = "index.";
System.out.println("Enter hero 1:");
hero1 = scanner.nextLine();
hero1builder += hero1;
hero1cls = Class.forName(hero1builder);
System.out.println("Hero 1 found");
```

All this code is inside of a try/catch and works as intended.
My challenge comes when I want to reference the variables inside of the class I reference.

At compile-time, java notices that the variable I want to reference here can't be resolved yet and it won't compile. How can I bypass this, so I can reference the variables inside of the class?

```
String[] hero1list = hero1cls.counterList;
```

I have tried numerous methods to reference the variable counterList, but none have worked. It's important that hero1cls stays dynamic, otherwise my program won't be able to function.

(In this example, index is the package, so index.Abaddon.counterList is what I want to reference. This works perfectly if I write it in explicitly like that.)(P.S. 2: This is not a problem of scope. counterList is the only thing that throws an error in this program, and methods such as hero1cls.getField() work.)

Here is an example of the classes I am referencing:

```
package index;

public class Abaddon {
    public static String[] counterList = {"Axe",
                   "AncientApparition",
                   "Doom",
                   "Lina",
                   "Lion",
                   "OutworldDevourer",
                   "ShadowDemon",
                   "Slark",
                   "Undying"
    };
}
```

Comment: Classes you make this way need to `implement` a common `interface`.  Look up those key words and how to code it. (Also, `classForName()` is almost certainly the wrong approach.  Just make a regular class, it'll be easier.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of `get(null)` and handle non-static member as well, you can create an instance of `Adaddon` by calling `clazz.newInstance()` as follows,

```
    String className = "index.Abaddon";
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("counterList");
    if (field.getType().isArray()) {
        final String[] arr = (String[]) field.get(clazz.newInstance());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

Comment: This works better, but I still get the error that "Field" cannot be resolved to a type. Do I need to import a library for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should exploit Java reflection method and in this particular case Class#getField method.
Here is the code:

```
String hero1builder = "index.";
System.out.println("Enter hero 1:");
hero1 = scanner.nextLine();
hero1builder += hero1;
hero1cls = Class.forName(hero1builder);
System.out.println("Hero 1 found");
Field counterListField = hero1cls.getField("counterList");
String[] counterList = (String[])counterListField.get(null);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counterList);
```

Note that the `counterList.get(null)` works only because `counterList` is a static field, otherwise you should have passed an instance the class Abaddon.

Comment: This is working fairly well, but the only problem is    get(null);    It says that it cannot invoke get null on the array type string. Also, the    getField    function returns a object type, not a field type, so I had to change it to object.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are saying. I've tested this code on your class and it works. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I think my answer solve the problem, if it doesn't let's see if I can fix it. What did you want to do / know more?

Comment: I've tried running this in jre 1.8 and 1.5. Both throw the error that Field cannot be resolved to a type and get(null) cannot be invoked on array type String.

Comment: you are right, i wrongly named the Field and the String[] variables with the same name! Now i have corrected it and it should work now

Comment: Your ide should resolve automatically the import for Field but in case it doesn't this is the import you should add: import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Comment: Thank you very much! The import was what I needed. For some reason eclipse wasn't working with Fields.